# Input a number and verify to a range

Tags: excel

I'm using excel, I want to input a number and verify it to a range. example my range is 86.1 +/- 1. I want to input a number and have it verify that its between the range. So if you type in 86.0 then you can continue, if you put 8.60 then it will prompt you. We have a lot of "fat fingering" going on, and I don't want to be able to continue if the input doesn't  fit in the range. I have no idea.....
Is there a formula to do this in excel?

I've tried using Fact and vlookup, but its not working

Comment: The best way to do this is with Worksheets_Change events, but that is vba.  You could always do a conditional format but that will only change the format of the cell, it will still allow them to exit the cell and move on.

Comment: This can also be done without VBA, using a custom data validation, something like: `=ABS([Cell address]-86)<1`

Comment: @Demetri, I forget about that.  I tend to lean towards vba too much that I forget that sometimes the wheel has already been invented.  Good call.

Comment: Would conditional formatting be appealing, too? Nice and simple, nice feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Data Validation from the ribbon? Validation criteria would be Allow Decimal, Data Between then put a minimum and maximum value.